# python Save the output of a shell command into a text file

Tags: python, shell

I want to save the output of a shell command into a textfile via python. This is my actual, pretty basic python code:

**Edit** *here is the final script, thank you for your help :)*

```
import subprocess

ip_adress_4 = 0    
pr = open("pointer_record.txt", "w")

while (ip_adress_4 < 255):
    ip_adress_4 = ip_adress_4 + 1
    ip_adress = '82.198.205.%d' % (ip_adress_4,)
    subprocess.Popen("host %s" % ip_adress, stdout=pr, shell=True)
```

Comment: I like to point out the `subprocess` documentation helped me get it working before. They are well written and worth your time. http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import subprocess
file_ = open("ouput.txt", "w")
subprocess.Popen("ls", stdout=file_)
```

**EDIT**: Matching your needs

```
import subprocess

file_ = open("ouput.txt", "w")
subprocess.Popen(["host", ipAddress], stdout=file_)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `subprocess.check_output` instead of `Popen` That will give you a string back containing the output, which you can then write out to the file.

Comment: Popen also allow you get the output. Even, directly to a file you have opened.

Comment: Like its name implies, `check_output` will check that the command succeeded.  This is often what you want, but many commands (like `diff` or `grep` for example) will signal an error even though the command performed exactly the job you requested -- `diff` returns nonzero when there were differences (so basically always when it does something useful); `grep` will fail if there were no matches.  You need to understand when this matters; way too many questions here are from people who blindly followed a suggestion like this, and then didn't know how to cope with the consequences.