# How do I write a command from Command Prompt to a file using Python?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Essentially, I want to create a script with multiple choices to check certain data on a hostname. For example, the code here will have an option to ping or run a `tracert` on a given hostname.

```
import os

print("""What did you want to run? (pick a number)
        (1) Ping
        (2) Traceroute""")

runit = raw_input("> ")

print ("Enter a hostname to check")
host = raw_input("> ") #accept input for hostname

if runit == "1":
    os.system("cmd /c ping " + host) 
elif runit == "2":
    os.system("cmd /c tracert " + host)
```

The code above works and I can get the results and manually copy them, but I would like this to be done automatically. I know I can open files using something like

```
p = open("ping1.txt", "w")
```

But I am not sure how to copy the results of the trace or the ping from the command prompt? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean write the output to a file?

Comment: Yes, I want to have the command run in command prompt, and then have it written to a file for viewing later or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python Save the output of a shell command into a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20421187/python-save-the-output-of-a-shell-command-into-a-text-file)

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9003522/2615940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to see the output and write to a file:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
print("""What did you want to run? (pick a number)
        (1) Ping
        (2) Traceroute""")

runit = raw_input("> ")

print ("Enter a hostname to check")
host = raw_input("> ") #accept input for hostname

if runit == "1":
    p  = Popen("cmd /c ping " + host, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    with open("ping.txt","w") as f:
        for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,""):
            print(line)
            f.write(line)

elif runit == "2":
     p = Popen("cmd /c tracert " + host, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
     with open("trace.txt", "w") as f:
         for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ""):
             print(line)
             f.write(line)
```

To keep the code dry and allow a user to choose again if they select the wrong choice, you can use a while loop with *str.format* with a dict to keep the options:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

opts = {"1": "ping", "2": "tracert"}

while True:
    print("""What did you want to run? (pick a number)
            (1) Ping
            (2) Traceroute""")
    runit = raw_input("> ")
    if runit in opts:
        host = raw_input("Enter a hostname to check\n> ")  # accept input for hostname
        p = Popen("cmd /c {} {}".format(opts[runit], host), shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
        with open("ping.txt", "w") as f:
            for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ""):
                print(line)
                f.write(line)
        break
    print("Invalid option")
```

Comment: Yes, this works exactly as I was hoping. Thanks a lot! still a bit unfamiliar with subprocess arguments like shell=1, stdout=PIPE, but I found the page and will read more up on it. I understand the rest and appreciate it!

Comment: No worries, you can normally get away with passing a list of individual args without setting shell=True but I don't ever use windows so I am not too sure if it would or not as I know some commands need shell=True when using window

Comment: 1- you could use `stdout=file` instead 2- no need to repeat the code. Compare with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37311520/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, 1. I am aware of how to redirect the output to a file, the OP wanted both the output to the shell and saved to a file which this provides.  2. The edit takes care of that, I would recommend you use a try/except in your code when casting  user input to int,  also you might consider using a dict as per my ans, your code will also error if a number > 2 is entered so that is also something you might want to catch.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: 1- could you point to a specific sentence in the question/comment where OP says that the output should be both to the file and stdout? 2- if you have comments about my answer; leave them under my answer (though, I don't think I need to pollute the answer to the [subprocess] question with unrelated to the question error handling of the user input. btw, I don't see where you follow your own recommendations (not that you should in this case).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, *Yes, this works exactly as I was hoping.*, that for me would be a good clue that I provided exactly how I interpreted the question considering it is from the person that asked it, as far as polluting the answers goes you may want to revisit your *2- no need to repeat the code*.

Comment: @Matt: do you need the output of the subprocess to a file *and* the console. Is it enough if the output goes only to the file?

Answer (score 0):

[`os.system(command)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) executes the command in a subshell and returns its exit status on most system (at least for cmd.exe).

The [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module is much for suitable for doing anything more than that.

You probably want to use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) which runs the command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

```
subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, universal_newlines=False)`
```

Comment: Once you have the output as a byte string the rest should be trivial. Although 'subprocess.check_output()' is probably not suitable if the command is not guaranteed to terminate as with `ping` if you dont specify a `-c count`. Then the solution proposed by Padraic Cunningham is better!

Answer (score -1):

To redirect the output of a command to a file, you could pass `stdout` parameter to [`subprocess.check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import subprocess

one_or_two = raw_input("""What did you want to run? (pick a number)
        (1) Ping
        (2) Traceroute
> """)
command = ["", "ping", "tracert"][int(one_or_two)]
host = raw_input("Enter a hostname to check\n> ") 

with open('output.txt', 'wb', 0) as file:
    subprocess.check_call([command, host], stdout=file)
```

If you want to display the output in the console in addition to copying the output to a file, see [Displaying subprocess output to stdout and redirecting it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25750468/4279).